# What is the best Latin counterpart for 'reach' or 'contact'?

Tags: vocabulary, idiom, verbs

In English you can use the verbs "reach" or "contact" to mean being in contact with someone without specifying the method.
When you don't want to specify whether you are writing a letter, knocking on a door, making a phone call, sending a messenger, or something else, these general verbs become very useful.

What would be the best Latin words for a general purpose like this?
I am not trying to find a word for a specific use case but to update my toolbox.
If the best answer depends on context — as it often does — then giving a couple of useful verbs and describing their use would be great.

I am willing to interpret the concept of a verb loosely.
If the thought is best conveyed by using an adverb or a noun, possibly together with a verb, that is perfectly fine.
I just want to figure out how to express the idea.